# Read Data From CSV File and set variables

Tags: csv, batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to accomplish a task and i don't know where to start unfortunately, hope you can assist me in the task.
I have a CSV file with 2 columns and i what to set 2 variables in my script that is based on that file.
i want to search a string in the 1st column and then based on the result set the 1st variable to be the string that i found in the 1st column and the 2nd variable i need it to be the string in the 2nd column right next to it.
so if i search a string and found it in row 33 i wish that the 1st variable will be the string in line 33 column 1 and the 2nd variable will be the string in line 33 column 2.
hope you can assist me \ direct me in the right direction...

thanks in advance for your help in this matter.
Cheers,
Maor Kuriel

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=," %%a in ('findstr /b /i "ypurstring" yourfilename') do set var1=%%a&set "var2=%%b"
echo variables are %var1% and %var2%
```

as a batch file - but you are very short on detail. There can be many gotchas.

Comment: thank you very much for the script, all i want is to find a string %userprofile%(mkuriel) for example I want to find it in a CSV file that contained a list of users :
mkuriel; maorkuriel
yking;YanivKing

i want to find the first string and set Var1=Mkuriel and Var2=maorkuriel
that is all i need to do... any loop holes in the batch you provided?

Comment: You should provide us with a relevant sample of your .csv file by editing it into your original question - it's the only way we can test the solution before presentinhg it.

Comment: the script and the csv file are located at http://1drv.ms/1BbcvN6
i would like that var1=mkuriel and var2=maorkuriel
thanks.